# Including Period Character (".") In A zmv Regex Range Filter

Tags: cron, zsh, glob

I'm trying to write a simple cronjob that recurses through the folders & files nested in `/OneDrive` and replaces file or folder name characters that are *not* `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, or `.` with an `_`.  (This strikes me as the easiest way to resolve syncing errors.)

Building off [this StackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271738/remove-all-special-characters-recursively-from-filename) I've managed to get *most* of the way there using:

```
zmv '**/*' '$f:h${${f:t}//[^A-Za-z0-9]/_}'
```

This regex expression, however, does *not* exclude `.`'s, which results in all of the file extensions in all of my folders being changed to `_`s (e.g. `file.txt` becomes `file_txt`).

I'm far from an advanced regex user, and all of the various permutations of this command I've used have thrown errors, including:

```
zmv '**/*' '$f:h${${f:t}//[^\.A-Za-z0-9]/_}'
zmv '**/*' '$f:h${${f:t}//[^.A-Za-z0-9]/_}'
zmv '**/*' '$f:h${${f:t}//[^A-Za-z0-9\.]/_}'
```

I'm sure the correct regex expression is obvious; I'm afraid it's just not obvious to me.

If anyone could provide some guidance here, along with a brief explanation of why my previous attempts didn't work, I'd be grateful for the small contribution to my understanding of regex.

Answer (score 1):

The `:h` modifier stripped out a slash; this has it added back in:

```
zmv '**/*' '$f:h/${${f:t}//[^\.A-Za-z0-9]/_}'
```

I'm not sure why that was missing from the original answer you referenced.

Some notes / caveats:

- the `-n` option for `zmv` can be very helpful in tracking down issues like this.
- a single call to `zmv` may not be able to rename both file names and directory names; multiple passes could be needed.
- `zmv` uses file globbing patterns. Globbing patterns are similar to regular expressions, but there are a number of significant differences, so a lot of documentation for regexes will not apply here.